# IP address char* variables unexpectedly changing when looping to gather addresses from ifa_addr

Tags: c, sockets, pointers, networking, ip-address

I am looping through a list of interfaces attempting to grab an IP address from each interface. I am observing a curious bug where the char* router_ip0 variable is being updated to the value of every other subsequent variable I set in the loop.

```
char *router_ip;
char *router_ip0;
char *router_ip1;
char *router_ip2;
char *router_ip3;
sockaddr_in *sa;

//Loop through list of interface's
for(tmp = ifaddr; tmp!=NULL; tmp=tmp->ifa_next){
    //Harvest IP address's
    if(tmp->ifa_addr->sa_family==AF_INET){
        if(!strncmp(&(tmp->ifa_name[3]),"eth0",4)){
            printf("\nin 0\n");
            sa = (struct sockaddr_in *) tmp->ifa_addr;
            router_ip0 = inet_ntoa(sa->sin_addr);
            printf("IP addr0: %s\n", router_ip0);
        }
        else if(!strncmp(&(tmp->ifa_name[3]),"eth1",4)){
            printf("\nin 1\n");
            sa = (struct sockaddr_in *) tmp->ifa_addr;
            router_ip1 = inet_ntoa(sa->sin_addr);
            printf("IP addr0: %s\n", router_ip0);
        }
        else if(!strncmp(&(tmp->ifa_name[3]),"eth2",4)){
            printf("\nin 2\n");
            sa = (struct sockaddr_in *) tmp->ifa_addr;
            router_ip2 = inet_ntoa(sa->sin_addr);
            printf("IP addr0: %s\n", router_ip0);
        }
        else{
            printf("\nin 3\n");
            sa = (struct sockaddr_in *) tmp->ifa_addr;
            router_ip3 = inet_ntoa(sa->sin_addr);
            //printf("IP addr: %s\n", router_ip1);
        }

}
```

The output is as follows.  I am fairly sure it can be verified that each variable is only set once in the loop. I suspect it may have something to do with assigning a pointer to another pointer with char* and the sa->sin_addr pointer.

> in 0
>    IP addr0: 10.0.0.1
>
> in 1
>    IP addr0: 10.1.0.1
>
> in 2
>    IP addr0: 10.2.0.1

As you can see, the value of router_ip0 is being changed to the value of router_ip1 and router_ip2 respectively.  The loop does not access interface 3 in this example.  If I comment out the assignment of router_ip1 and router_ip2 I get the expected output

> in 0 
>   IP addr0: 10.0.0.1
>
> in 1 
>   IP addr0: 10.0.0.1
>
> in 2 
>   IP addr0: 10.0.0.1

It would be a great help if someone could explain what might be going on here. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `malloc` and `strcpy` to save the returned string to allocated memory. Right now all your `char` pointers are pointing to the same address on the stack, at the returned string from `inet_ntoa`, which gets cleared when you exit the scope and then recreated in the next loop. This overwrites the stack memory that contained the last returned string, making it look like your variables changed.

For instance, before your `for` loop, you could do:

```
char *result;
router_ip0 = (char*)malloc(16);
router_ip1 = (char*)malloc(16);
router_ip2 = (char*)malloc(16);
router_ip3 = (char*)malloc(16);
```

(16 = max length of an IPv4 string + 1 for null termination char)

Then in the loop's `if` blocks:

```
...
if(!strncmp(&(tmp->ifa_name[3]),"eth0",4)){
    printf("\nin 0\n");
    sa = (struct sockaddr_in *) tmp->ifa_addr;
    result = inet_ntoa(sa->sin_addr);
    strcpy(router_ip0, result);
    printf("IP addr0: %s\n", router_ip0);
}
else if...
```

Then after the loop:

```
free(router_ip0);
free(router_ip1);
free(router_ip2);
free(router_ip3);
```

You could also use char arrays of size 16 instead of char pointers to achieve the same effect without having to worry about `malloc` and `free`.